# Remove html tag judging by its content?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, tags

I'm trying to remove all instances of `<p><a class="link" href="Dynamic-URL">Dynamic Title</a>:</p>`

I removed the tags individually, but that still leaves me with `:` and even if I remove that, all `:` are removed from within any `<p>`

Is there a way to remove the `<p>` tag and its contents only if it contains `a.link`?

Comment: how did you remove? `jquery`? where it is?

Comment: Please add a FIDDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1Ljgnkut/

**HTML**

```
<a href = "#">One</a>
<p>
  <a class = "link" href = "#">Two</a>:
</p>
<p>
  <a class = "link" href = "#">Three</a>:
</p>
<a class = "link" href = "#">Four</a>
```

**JavaScript** (using jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("p .link").closest("p").remove();

});
```

Comment: Thank you! That was such an easy fix.

Comment: Please consider up-voting my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

So what wrong with this, this will checking for all `p` tag, if contains `a.link` in returned removed it:

```
 $('p').has('a.link').remove()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/cvfqd1kj/)

Comment: Succinct Answer. Liked it.

Comment: And you deserved it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all instances of `<p><a class="link" href="Dynamic-URL">Dynamic Title</a>:</p>` by this line of jquery:

```
$("p a.link")
```

Then you can loop over all elements in array and remove them one by one like this:

```
   $("p a.link").each(function(){
     $(this).remove();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out such approach to address your issue

```
$("p").each(function(){
    if((this).siblings("a").hasClass("link"))
    {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("p > a.link").parent().remove();
```